# Jest not printing test results after react is imported

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, reactjs, jestjs

I'm writing tests for react. But when I require react, jest just prints `Waiting on 1 test...`, and then finishes without telling me the result of the test.

```
jest.dontMock('../src/scripts/components/register/Register.jsx');

describe('Register', function () {
    it('Should validate', function () {
        var React = require('react/addons');
        var Register = require('../src/scripts/components/register/Register.jsx');
        // var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
        //
        // var register = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        //     <Register/>
        // )
        expect(true).toBe(false);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by

```
    nvm install 0.10
    nvm use 0.10
    npm rebuild
    npm t
```

For some reason jest doesn't play nice with the current stable version of node.